# Self-join in SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: sql, ssas, bids

I have a table like this:

> ```
> WordId      Set1   Set2    Related-wordId
> ---------   ----   -----   --------
> 101          A      C1      105
> 102          B      C2      101
> 103          A      C1      102
> ```

Then I need to getting the association rules between Word's Set1 and Related-word's Set2.

I've used self-referencing and define case/nested tables but at the result of dependency graph there is no difference between word's Set1 or Set2 and parent-word's Set1 or Set2!

What is the best solution for this Text-mining problem in SQL Server Analysis Services project?

Comment: @ARZ: Please elaborate more what you require.

Comment: I have a words table .each word has one related word and I want to detect all association rules between some attributes of the base word and related word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-Join in SSAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607663/self-join-in-ssas)

Answer (score 0):

In Analysis Services Templates We can use self Join query to do this

To open a template, right-click the template name and select Open, or drag the template into a query window that you already opened. After the query window is open, you can use commands on the toolbar or Query menu to help you build statements:

To check the syntax of a query, click Parse.

To run a query, click Execute.

To stop a query that is running, click Cancel Executing Query.

View the results of a query in the Results tab at the bottom of the screen.

Switch to the Messages tab to see the number of records returned, errors, query statements, and any other messages that are associated with the execution of the query. For example, if you execute a DAX statement against a model running in Direct Query mode, you can see the Transact-SQL statement that is generated by the xVelocity in-memory analytics engine (VertiPaq).

Comment: _SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio_ doesn't have any _Template Explorer_ view!